# How to get spacing in math mode without just repeating fixed spaces (tilde ~)?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, tilde

I'm looking for a way to move text in my equation, instead of just shoving multiple `~~~~` until it's in the right position. I'm quite new to LaTeX, what exactly would be the command?

I'm also looking for a way such that this command won't move the position of anything anything before it, but of course moves forward everything in front.

Right now I have:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

I'm trying to increase the distance between the end of the fraction and the start of the text "for".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried `\quad` and/or `\qquad` to create the desired gap?

Comment: using `\text{...}` instead of `\mbox{...}` is recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using nested `equation*` and `aligned` environments, you could use a single `align*` environment. Two additional suggesions: (i) for the separation between the equation and condition parts, you could employ `\qquad` ("double `\quad`"); (ii) for a bit more vertical separation between the two rows, you could `[1ex]` immediately after the first `\\` line break instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0 \qquad\text{for $0 \leq y \leq b$} \\[1ex]
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0 \qquad\text{for $0 \leq x \leq a$} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: better to use `&&` before the `\text` just in case what is on the right-hand side of the `=` signs isn't always the same width.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Good point. I guess I was working with what the OP stated he/she wants to get typeset...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the equations numbered (since you are using `aligned`), just adding a `&&` after the `= 0` on each row will insert a `\quad` = 1em horizontal gap between the equation and what follows AND left-align the following content (a single `&` would also add the 1em gap, but right-align what follows).  The `aligned` type environments are aligned `rlrlrl...`, with a 1em gap after each left-aligned field.

An alternative method is also shown here, with a TABstack, in which the horizontal and vertical gaps between the equation parts may be independently specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
Original
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Extra alignment tab in aligned environment
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0&&     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0&&     \mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
a tabstack with vertical and horizontal gap size set
\setstackaligngap{3em}
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\begin{equation*}
\alignShortstack{
\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0 &&\mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b \\
\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0 &&\mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a \\
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other alternatives for horizontal space in equations, when tab alignment is not the appropriate method, can be accomplished either with `\hspace{length}`, with `\kern length`, or with `\mkern mu-length`.  Additionally, as was pointed out in the comments, `\quad` and `\qquad` also insert "typical" (recommended?) math separations.  With `\hspace`, inserted glue can be a factor (though I don't know if that is relevant in math mode), whereas no glue will be inserted about kerns.

Answer (score 0):

The `alignat` environment can do what you want. Here are two suggestions — the second one requires using the `mathtools` package, which loads amsmath anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}

\noindent A first solution:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0 & \hspace{4em} & \mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0  &  &  \mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a + 1
\end{alignat}
Or even,  keeping the first column centred:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} &= 0 & \hspace{4em} & \mathrlap{\mbox{ for } 0 \leq y \leq b} \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y} &= 0  &  & \mathrlap{\mbox{ for } 0 \leq x \leq a  + 1}
\end{alignat}
 \end{document}
```

[image]